# How do I find specific rows in a csv file and add together certain values from those rows?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a task that needs to be completed by a class of students that I am currently unable to work out.  I've got reasonably basic skills with python but am trying to learn as best I can.

The students are working on a case study related to a vehicle leasing company.  They lease three types of vehicles, Hatch, Sedan or SUV, and a monthly lease cost is calculated for each customer.  This data is stored in a CSV file in the following format:

[cars.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCHnG.png)

I need to be able to do the following:

1. Search through the file to find all vehicles of a particular type (e.g. SUV)
2. Add together all the monthly costs for that particular vehicle type (in this instance, 350 + 450 for a total of 800)
3. write a summary to another file listing the vehicle type and the total monthly cost

I have been browsing for a while and I'm just not really sure where to go with this.

Would anyone be able to help out with the code to achieve this?  I'm sure someone with decent knowledge will be able to do this a lot easier than I'm finding it.

Thank you

Comment: Show us the attempts you made.

Comment: Do you want to groupby based on vehicle type and get sum of the cost?

Comment: Sadly, no previous attempts, sorry.  As I said, I only have basic knowledge and am trying to expand this. I can create and write a CSV file but am unsure about this particular task.

And yes, I am essentially wanting to group all the of the same vehicle type together and sum the costs associated with that particular vehicle type.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done using the Pandas in Python https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html.

```
 # first of all we read the csv:

 df = pd.read_csv('cars.csv')

 # Group by Type and sum by monthly cost
 result = df[['vehicle', 'cost']].groupby('vehicle').sum()

 # Convert result to a new file
 result.to_csv('new_file.csv')
```

The result will look be similar to this:

[image]

Comment: What you have above here people is a huge help.  But, is there a way to do this without using pandas?  Pandas is not a part of the standard Python package, right?  Comes with a package called Anaconda, is that correct?
I'm thinking of what the kids might have installed on their laptops and whether they would need to install additional software and how difficult this would be for them.

Comment: You can install packages based on your need, as in your case it is `pandas` and you don't need to install `Anaconda`. Just run `pip install pandas` in command prompt and it will only install `pandas`  and it's dependencies for you .

Comment: Thanks again for that.  I've been using Thonny as my editor and found in there how to install it after your suggestion.  As i said, I have basic knowledge and I'm trying to build on that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'vehicle': ['Hatch', 'Sedan', 'SUV', 'SUV', 'Sedan'], 'term': [4,3,5,3,4], 'cost': [300,400,350,450,400]})

df = df.groupby('vehicle').agg('sum').reset_index()

df.to_csv('demo.csv', index=False)
```

Your data frame will look like this:

```
   vehicle   term   cost
0   Hatch      4    300
1   SUV        8    800
2   Sedan      7    800
```

Comment: How will this code work with more data?  The csv I uploaded was an example to show what I want to achieve, but what if the file has for example, upward of 100, or even an unknown number of rows?

Comment: You can load your csv as a data frame using `df=pd.read_csv("path of csv file")`

Comment: Without pandas, you can do it by loading it as a file then write logic to keep track of the operations, as you do normal Read Write operation

Comment: Pandas do the job nicely, but I'm also cautious that this means the kids (and myself) will be able to skip the understanding of how the the data is sorted and searched.  Would you have any sample of how I could achieve the same thins without using pandas?  Even if it's not sample code, maybe steps that I would need to go through to do this?  I can hopefully piece the logic together and find what I would need to write.